# RRAS Svr on win 2003 provides same gateway as the ip to vpn clients and subnet as 255.255.255.255

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, rras

I've setup a RRAS Svr on win 2003 svr, to provide VPN access to clients.  I've followed all directions in microsoft documentation to finish the setup.

A VPN client successfully connects when I connect to the VPN svr.  But when I look at the ipconfig info, I see that the IP and Gateway are same and subnet is 255.255.255.255.

Example
IP - 10.0.0.121
Gateway - 10.0.0.121
subnet - 255.255.255.255
DNS - 10.0.0.12

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. What you're seeing is perfectly normal. The VPN client's gateway is the VPN assigned ip address itself. Are you having a problem once connected to the VPN?

Comment: Yes.  I cant get to any of the machines in the network once connected.

Comment: You need to make sure that LAN routing is enabled on the RRAS server, otherwise you'll only have access to the server and not the LAN that the server is connected to. The VPN network is a different network from the LAN and without enabling LAN routing on the RRAS server you'll be unable to access the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the ipv4 address pool assignment ? Is the GW IP part of this pool ?

Comment: I'm using DHCP to assign IP addresses.  And the IP assigned to client is from DHCP pool is correct, so that part seems to be ok.

Comment: I tough from your post that the client was getting the ip address of the server. Yes, that should be the right.

Comment: If you wish to ask additional questions, please comment on the question instead of posting an answer :)